# How can I get used RAM in percent?

Tags: java, android, ram

I'm trying to get the percentage of used RAM, but this code just gives me the used RAM in MB. How can I get it in percent?

```
private void Used(){
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
    long used = TotalRam() - availableMegs ;
    crpv.setPercent();
    crpv.setPercent(used);
    tvPercent.setText(used+" MB");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double percentUsed = 1.0 * used / TotalRam();
```

Comment: Thanks, I added Simple change
 used = 100 * used / TotalRam();